# Cannot get bookmarks to populate

Tags: vba, ms-word, reference, userform, bookmarks

Thanks for your help in advance

I'm writing my first userform - after hours of reading, try and repeat this is what I came up with

```
Private Sub btnSubmit_Click()
 
Dim txtVorname As Range
Set txtVorname = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("Vornamebkmk").Range
txtVorname.Text = "Some more text here."
ActiveDocument.Bookmarks.Add "Vornamebkmk", txtVorname
ActiveDocument.Fields.Update
 
Me.Repaint
 
UserForm1.Hide
 
End Sub
```

I am trying to insert into bookmarks and set reference from those to other parts of the document.
The problem is: it will show me "Some more text here." But I cannot get to set the bookmark a second time. THerefore the references are not working.

I thinkg the bookmark itself is preserved. Therefore the reinsertion of the data of my userform is not working, meaning:

```
ActiveDocument.Bookmarks.Add "Vornamebkmk", txtVorname
```

... is not working.

I read all the help I could find. But somehow I am missing something

Can you spot what my code misses?

Comment: Here are my two basic resources for userforms: http://www.gmayor.com/Userform.htm and http://gregmaxey.com/word_tip_pages/create_employ_userForm.html.

Comment: Can you step through what happens, please? It sounds as if you are successfully inserting text, but then what? Does the .Bookmarks. Add call succeed? If so, what exactly goes wrong after that? If you click the button again, wouldn't you expect the same action to be repeated?

Comment: The macro will insert "Some more text here." And the reference will show the same. That means to me the bookmark itself is preserved. Therefore the reinsertion of the data of my userform is not working (meaning from line 5 on)

Comment: @CharlesKenyon: Thanks. Actually I adapted most of the code from gregmaxey. But I will check out gmayor,too.

Comment: Your code seems to work OK here - not sure I have understood the problem. I stepped through (put a breakpoint on the "Set txtVorname" line, run the code that loads the form. Probably also useful to make your bookmarks visible in FIle->Options>Advanced, or use the VBE Immediate Window to check the value of ActiveDocument.Bookmarks.Count after each statement). I can see the bookmark before I start, see it disappear when the "txtVorname.Text =" line is executed and see it reappear when the .Bookmarks.Add line is executed, see REF fields that reference that bookmark updated. What do you see?